# How can I add an input id value (iteration-based) in a while loop that references a piece of html outside of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop

My requirement is as follows: I have a select that is used to add input fields to a form based on the number selected. These new input fields share the same ID and that's a problem. I'd like to add a number to the id so that the code is valid. What makes it complex is the fact that the script uses a while loop and it references a piece of html outside of the method (change) that triggers the loop. I don't know what to modify to make it work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's a working example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wzevjkb2/3/

My script:

```
if ($('#returnRequest').length) {
    var wrapper = $('#productRowWrapper'),
        head = $("#noa_header"),
        div =
            '<div class="form-group row">' +
            '<div class="col-md-4 control-item">' +
            '<label class="control-label">* Serial number</label>' +
            '<input type="text" class="form-control requiredSerialN" name="requiredSerialN_1" />' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-md-4 control-item">' +
            '<label class="control-label">* Item is</label>' +
            '<select class="form-control requiredItemIs" name="returnProdItemIs_1">' +
            '<option value="">Select</option>' +
            '<option value="1">New and unopened</option>' +
            '<option value="2">Defective</option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-md-4 control-item">' +
            '<label class="control-label">* You request</label>' +
            '<select class="form-control requiredYouRequest" name="returnProdYouRequest_1">' +
            '<option value="">Select</option>' +
            '<option value="1">Replacement</option>' +
            '<option value="2">Credit only</option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';

    $('#quantityReturn').change(function () {

        var val = parseInt($(this).val());
        val ? (head.show()) : head.hide();

        while (wrapper.children().length > val)
        wrapper.children().last().remove();

        while (wrapper.children().length < val)
        wrapper.append(div);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert that div template into a jquery object and alter the id value, this is just one method, in programming one thing can be achieved in a lot of ways. But this will get the job done

```
if ($('#returnRequest').length) {

    var wrapper = $('#productRowWrapper'),
        head = $("#noa_header"),
        div =
            $('<div class="form-group row" />').html('<div class="col-md-4 control-item">' +
            '<label class="control-label">* Serial number</label>' +
            '<input type="text" class="form-control requiredSerialN" name="requiredSerialN_1" />' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-md-4 control-item">' +
            '<label class="control-label">* Item is</label>' +
            '<select class="form-control requiredItemIs" name="returnProdItemIs_1">' +
            '<option value="">Select</option>' +
            '<option value="1">New and unopened</option>' +
            '<option value="2">Defective</option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-md-4 control-item">' +
            '<label class="control-label">* You request</label>' +
            '<select class="form-control requiredYouRequest" name="returnProdYouRequest_1">' +
            '<option value="">Select</option>' +
            '<option value="1">Replacement</option>' +
            '<option value="2">Credit only</option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '</div></br>');

    $('#quantityReturn').change(function () {

        var val = parseInt($(this).val());
        val ? head.show() : head.hide();

        while (wrapper.children(".row").length > val)
        wrapper.children(".row").last().remove();

        for (var i = wrapper.children(".row").length; i < val; i++) {
            var tmp=div.clone();
            tmp.find(".requiredSerialN").attr("id","requiredSerialN_"+i);
            tmp.find(".requiredItemIs").attr("id","returnProdItemIs_"+i);
            tmp.find(".requiredYouRequest").attr("id","returnProdYouRequest_"+i);
            wrapper.append(tmp);
        };
    });
}
```

[DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/wzevjkb2/4/)